# Date validation using ng-pattern is working, but also its get submitted when its in error

Tags: angularjs

In my form I used ng-pattern for date, when i entered the wrong pattern and submit the form, its get submitted. Here my code.

```
<form role="form" name="editForm" ng-submit="saveRecord()">
    <label class="control-label">DATE</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userRecord.date" ng-pattern='/^((0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](19|20)[0-9]{2})*$/'
           name="date" class="form-control" required/>
           <div role="alert">
               <span style="color:red" ng-show="editForm.date.$dirty">
                   <span ng-show="editForm.date.$error.pattern">Incorrect Format, should be MM/DD/YYYY</span>
                   <span ng-show="editForm.date.$error.required">date is required.</span>
               </span>
           </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button> 
</form>
```

It will display the error also, but if i submit the form its get submited.
I have tried with several searches but could not find solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can go down 2 paths:

1. Disable the form button as long as the form is invalid
2. You need to check in your form submit function if the form is valid or not

**Solution 1**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<form role="form" name="editForm" ng-submit="saveRecord(editForm.$valid)">
```

And now in your controller do the next in the saveRecord function:

```
$scope.saveRecord = function(valid) {
   if(!valid) { return; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed `novalidate` directory in form tag

like

```
<form role="form" name="editForm" ng-submit="saveRecord()" novalidate>
```

and edit also validate with submit button like

```
 ng-show="editForm.$submitted && editForm.date.$error.pattern"
 ng-show="editForm.$submitted && editForm.date.$error.required"
```

i hope its help

Comment: Sorry kishor, its not working.., when i use `code` ng-show="editForm.$submitted && editForm.date.$error.pattern"
 ng-show="editForm.$submitted && editForm.date.$error.required" `code` validation is not working.

Comment: $scope.saveRecord = function(valid) {
   if($scope.editform) { return ; }
}

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to stop submitting page if pattern does not match

```
<span class="error" style="color:red" ng-show="externalLinkForm.link.$error.pattern">
                                Please use hash</span>
```

To study detail about the validation rule needed in ng-pattern please see the link to get in detail of the validation rules

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp